# How to Change colorPrimary value by Java/Kotlin code?

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to change colorPrimary value when I click some button.But I don't know how to implement it.

```
    <style name="Theme.Life.Light"  parent="***" >
    
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item> 

    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item> 
    </style>
```

just like the coede show,I want to change **colorPrimary** by Java/Kotlin code.

what should I do?

Comment: you cannot change color primary but you make two or more themes with other colors and switch themes according to your button click

Comment: Ok,thank you! I think I have known how to do finish my destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These colors are defined in Theme and can not be changed programmatically. Instead you can change colors manually or change color of specific View individually.